# How to parse JSON to Class in Kotlin (non standard format)

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I have the following JSON format:

```
{
  "July 2019": [
    {
      "id": 6783,
      "home_team": "Team Name",
      ...
    },
    {...}
  ],
  "August 2019" : [
    {
      "id": 6783,
      "home_team": "Team Name",
      ...
    },
    {...}
  ],
  ...
}
```

I am trying to parse it from JSON using gson in to Kotlin classes, for which I have the following:

```
inner class Fixture(val id: Int, val home_team: String)

inner class Fixtures(val date: String, val fixtures: ArrayList<Fixture>)
```

I am then using OkHTTPClient to download the JSON and try to parse it using:

```
val body = response.body?.string()
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val fixtures = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Fixtures>::class.java).toList()
```

The body is parsed correctly (I see it in debugger) but the classes are not created and LOGCAT gives me:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I assume this is because the date is in an object and not array but I have no idea how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post your data class `Fixtures`  and also your API endpoint.

Comment: `Array<Fixtures>::class.java` expects an array of form `[...]` and what you have is an object of form `{...}`. You can parse your json into a `Map<String, List<Fixture>>`.

Comment: @SqueezyMo ah, I didn't know you could do it like a map. then my answer is incorrect :) and your solution should work then yeah

Comment: Yes, it's doable with a `TypeToken`: `gson.fromJson(body, object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<Fixture>>>() {}.type)`

Comment: @SqueezyMo I now get `Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : Any!> fromJson(p0: String!, p1: Type!): T!
Please specify it explicitly.`

Comment: Just specify it explicitly :) `gson.fromJson<Map<String, List<String>>>(body, object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.type)`

Comment: @SqueezyMo awesome thanks it works! (I'm very new to Kotlin, coming from Web, PHP & Swift)